# Separate Text and number from Alphanumeric text using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spyder

I have a excel sheet containing lot of data in Column A and Column B as shown below. Column B always begins alphabet M and then number.

```
   A         B
Pradeep440  M440
Azhar541    M541
Venkat456   M456
Akash144    M144
Vipul157    M157
Fairo452    M452
Akshay449   M449
Pavan249    M249
Asad114     M114
Rudra890    M890
Niranjan120 M120
Darshan334  M334
Veeresh876  M876
```

Expected output:

```
    A         B      C 
Pradeep440  M440    440
Azhar541    M541    541
Venkat456   M456    456
Akash144    M144    144
Vipul157    M157    157
Fairo452    M452    452
Akshay449   M449    449
Pavan249    M249    249
Asad114     M114    114
Rudra890    M890    890
Niranjan120 M120    120
Darshan334  M334    334
Veeresh876  M876    876
```

Can someone guide me how to split it or separate it using python, I am new to python.Appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please explain this row in the output: `Azhar541    M541    531`

Comment: Oops its a mistake it should be 541 in output

Comment: Got it. Fixed your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `extract`:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].str.extract('(\d+)$')[0]
```

Comment: @yQuang thanks for your code When i run it i get error as "    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'B'" Also i have data from Row1

Comment: Replace `'B'` with your actual column name?

Comment: But I didnt define Column B since the data in excel sheet starts from Row1, basically the columns are not defined

Answer (score 3):

Do with `strip`

```
df['C']=df.B.str.strip('M')
df
Out[132]: 
              A     B    C
0    Pradeep440  M440  440
1      Azhar541  M541  541
2     Venkat456  M456  456
3      Akash144  M144  144
4      Vipul157  M157  157
5      Fairo452  M452  452
6     Akshay449  M449  449
7      Pavan249  M249  249
8       Asad114  M114  114
9      Rudra890  M890  890
10  Niranjan120  M120  120
11   Darshan334  M334  334
12   Veeresh876  M876  876
```

Comment: thanks for your code When i run it i get error as "    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'B'" Also i have data from Row1

Answer (score 1):

As you have fix formate you can skip first char from string

```
df["C"] = df.B.str[1:]
```

or

```
df["C"] = df.iloc[:,1].str[1:]
```

```
df
              A     B    C
0    Pradeep440  M440  440
1      Azhar541  M541  541
2     Venkat456  M456  456
3      Akash144  M144  144
4      Vipul157  M157  157
5      Fairo452  M452  452
6     Akshay449  M449  449
7      Pavan249  M249  249
8       Asad114  M114  114
9      Rudra890  M890  890
10  Niranjan120  M120  120
11   Darshan334  M334  334
12   Veeresh876  M876  876
```

Comment: thanks for your code When i run it i get error as "    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'B'" Also i have data from Row1

Comment: If you have don't have columns name then please update same in question.